# Menu bar is shown on the container in flutter

Tags: drop-down-menu

I am trying to show the menu  below the container but it is shown on the container. I tried different methods but all failed.

Comment: Please update [edit] and update the question with code snippet and also tag relevant programming languages

Comment: Are you asking about side menu(drawer) like [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/2160/1*XI9fZg1LOnnQNEaRxPYVQA.png) or something else?

Comment: no no drop down menu